# Is there a software project index?

Tags: list, version-control, open-source, project, issue-tracking

I am working on a platform to collect various data of software projects (e.g. code repository, issues, etc). Now I would like to create an index over software project, but before I do so on my own, I wanted to ask whether such an index already exists.

Ideally, such an index would list various (open source) software projects and offer data and URLs related to them. What I would need is at least the project name as well as the URLs to the code repository and to the issue tracker. An API to gather this information then would make it perfect.

Is anybody aware of such an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you come across ohloh.net? It's the closest thing I can think of from what you have stated.